# Windows Phone self-evaluation: let's get critical!

Tags: discussion, status-completed

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :)

Answer (score 4):

[How to get rid of the music player buttons when not playing music/podcast/etc?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/532/how-to-get-rid-of-the-music-player-buttons-when-not-playing-music-podcast-etc)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I feel like this is a good question. The author prevents a problem very clearly, and was answered with two solutions. The first being reboot your phone, and the other an app. +1

Comment: And this is a very common question Windows Phone users do to me.

Answer (score 3):

[When is a new app rating displayed in the marketplace?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/565/after-you-rate-an-app-in-the-phone-when-it-syncs-with-marketplace)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This is another good question/answer set. It did need some grammar fixes and I went ahead and did that. What I like about this is that it isn't a Google question. By that I mean *at the time* the answer wasn't found by pointing him to the first search result.

Comment: Thanks @Joe. It was my question. ;)   This kind of question is very difficult to find in Microsoft Answer. And I think there isn't comments about this in Microsoft channels at all.

Comment: I think first paragraph of the answer should be removed as it is not certain and slightly snarky. The other two paragraphs are good.

Answer (score 3):

[Remove contact picture](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/542/remove-contact-picture)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I had the same doubt. Very upvoted.

Comment: The question is fine, but I don't like the answers. So many of our answers are `No, you can't` and I don't like that. I think we need to work better on answers like that. [related meta post](http://meta.windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/40/will-we-allow-no-and-not-currently-possible-answers-what-to-do-about-them/)

Answer (score 2):

[What are the limitations of a device with 256 MB of RAM?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/557/what-are-the-limitations-of-a-device-with-256-mb-of-ram)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This question is very specific and in Microsoft Channels this information is separated in every section.

Answer (score 1):

[Internet Explorer doesn't start at all](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/537/internet-explorer-doesnt-start-at-all)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: It is something about bugs. In the majority of the cases it will be very specific. But many bugs have a common solition across users so it is valid.

Comment: I Like this because it shows we aren't just a repository of what features the phone has or doesn't have, and instead we will do our best to help you with your problem. +1

Answer (score 1):

[Is it possible to play videos from OneDrive in the phone?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/528/is-it-possible-to-play-videos-from-skydrive-in-the-phone)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Yes, you can see pictures but you can't see videos you uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

[Is it possible to use transparent PNG in ME tile and lockscreen?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/553/is-it-possible-to-use-transparent-png-in-me-tile-and-lockscreen)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This question slightly confused me when I read the title since it has PNG and ME in capitals, as I wasn't familiar with the `Me` title I thought it was an acronym for something. It also sometimes uses `png` in lowercase, so it possibly could be cleaned up a bit.

Comment: The answer possibly has too many screenshots, one or two would probably suffice.

Comment: I agree with @row1 this question is is need of cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

[How can I sync the profile picture of my contacts to my online Live.com account?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/516/how-to-sync-contacts-with-photos)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This question was also pretty sloppy. I did my best to clean it up while keeping what the asker had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

[Change Phone Number Stored On Sim](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/501/change-phone-number-stored-on-sim)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score -1):

[Orientation of photos sent from Android devices?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/521/orientation-of-photos-sent-from-android-devices)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I  have never really liked this one. I really want to close it as Too Localized, but other people thought it was good. How are we supposed to test this? What camera app is being used? Which Android phone? From all or just 1? I feel like this question need drastic improvement, or should be closed.

Comment: The question might be slightly better if it was something like "Does Windows Phone always use the rotation EXIF data?". Otherwise it feels like it half-belongs on here and half on the Android site.